# mdadm completely re-syncs the raid5 member but looses every time after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm

While installing win10 I might have accidentally overwritten on a `raid5` member (3 disk setup). So used ubuntu livecd to re-add the disk and re-sync it (took 6 hours). But after I reboot the disk is again lost from the array and not detected as raid member even by `gparted`. so entire re-sync had to be done again. Already happened twice.

What is the step I am missing?

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10]
md1 : active raid5 sda[4] sdb[1] sde[3]
      3906764800 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [3/2] [_UU]
      [===========>.........]  recovery = 55.6% (1086304028/1953382400) finish=147.5min speed=97935K/sec
      bitmap: 0/15 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

mdadm detail:

```
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat Sep 21 14:09:01 2019
        Raid Level : raid5
        Array Size : 3906764800 (3725.78 GiB 4000.53 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 1953382400 (1862.89 GiB 2000.26 GB)
      Raid Devices : 3
     Total Devices : 3
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Sat Jul 31 13:07:35 2021
             State : clean, degraded, recovering
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 3
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 1

            Layout : left-symmetric
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

    Rebuild Status : 55% complete

              Name : vikas-asus-raid:1  (local to host vikas-asus-raid)
              UUID : ffe5d84b:45323883:86650996:ad3cb535
            Events : 44221

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       4       8        0        0      spare rebuilding   /dev/sda
       1       8       16        1      active sync   /dev/sdb
       3       8       64        2      active sync   /dev/sde
```

`sudo parted -l`:

```
Error: The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will
be used.
OK/Cancel? ok
Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRZ-00Z (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2000GB  2000GB  fat32


Error: /dev/sdb: unrecognised disk label
Model: ATA WDC WD20EURX-63T (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: unknown
Disk Flags:

Model: ATA WDC WD20EZRX-00D (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdd: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End  Size  Type  File system  Flags


Model: WDC WD32 00BPVT-55ZEST0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sde: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1048kB  53.3GB  53.3GB  extended                  boot
 5      1049kB  53.3GB  53.3GB  logical   ext4
 3      53.3GB  102GB   49.2GB  primary   ext4
 2      102GB   202GB   100GB   primary   ext4
 4      308GB   320GB   11.8GB  primary   linux-swap(v1)


Model: Linux Software RAID Array (md)
Disk /dev/md1: 4001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  4001GB  4001GB  ext4
```

Comment: Is it detected as _something else_ (by gparted, or by lsblk -f)?

Comment: While syncing gparted says its a linux raid member. But after reboot the block device is detected but as unallocated.

Comment: "Unallocated" is normal: gparted works with partition tables, and you don't have a partition table on the disk (it directly has mdraid on it). What do `mdadm -E /dev/sda` and `blkid /dev/sda` detect *after reboot, before syncing*?

Comment: its syncing for the third time now. I cant answer that right now. But what should I do to make the sync stay after it finishes?

Comment: No, you should find out *why* it's happening first.

Comment: /dev/sda:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)

The magic on the disk1 does not match the other two.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself. mdadm acts different from other disks during shutdown. The mdadm superblock was never written to disk automatically. It was written when the mdadm is stopped. Apparently a shutdown system should do that. But mdadm was not gracefull at shutdown and took a full 1m:30s timeout to be forcefully killed. So the reboot did not find the disk again.

Later I stopped mdadm in between the sync. That caused it to flush the superblock to the disk. The next reboot the disk was automatically found and the incomplete sync was even resumed. Once the superblock was flushed, even after sync, all systems were normal again.

I still dont know what was my error for this behaviour. But glad this got sorted. Degraded raid5 array is like a hanging sword.